# Can i set a specific transformation, for my Feature Dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

Using ArcMap, i created a 'Feature Dataset (FD)' and set it to WGS84, F23s.

If i export a shapefile in SAD69 F23s, to this FD, it automatically project the shapefile to WGS, using the "SAD_1969_To_WGS_1984_**14**" transformation (WKID 1877).

I want to make the same operation, but instead of using this transformation, using the "SAD_1969_To_WGS_1984_**13**" (WKID 1876).

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain "the way i need", and what transformation is used instead? What software are you using?

Comment: I edited my post, so i think its better explained.

Comment: Those two transforms cover two distinct areas. Is your data in Brazil or Venezuela?

Comment: My entire data is in Brazil. But for some determinations of the company who hired us, we must use the 14.

Answer (score 1):

A transformation is used when projecting features from one Coordinate System to another.  A Feature Dataset does not *store* the transformation, but rather the features are stored in the Coordinate System they have been saved in.  The transformation happens at projection.

You will need to project your features first, selecting the desired transformation when projecting.

See [Project - ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm)

Once they have been projected you can then load them into the Feature Dataset.

Comment: But i did some tests, and the system apply a transformation, just simply exporting the shapefile to a Feature Dataset. So, it does the project with some transformation.
I just want to set up exactly which one, i want to use.

Comment: +1 If you need to store the geotransformation used for each feature, I suppose you could add an field and populate it with the [Wkid of the geotransformation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Datum_transformations/02r3000000r8000000/), e.g. `6195` for `SAD_1969_96_To_WGS_1984_2`.

Comment: see http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000002828

Comment: @raphael to specify the transformation use the project tool rather than an export. The project tool will allow you to specify the transformation

Comment: Guys, i know how to project it with the tool. Even in batch mode, to multiple shapefiles. My question is not that.
Since the 'export' already does some transformation, i just want to specify one kind and enjoy this facility,

Comment: @raphael this was not your question - if that's what you want to know you need to make that clear in your question, including an example of how you performed the export

Comment: I edited my post, so i think its better explained.

Comment: Try setting the default transformation in the gp environment, but you may have to use a gp tool rather than "catalog."

Comment: @mkennedy I suggest to turn your comment into a valuable answer.